# Object disappears when zooming out

Tags: python, objects, scale

I am on blender, and I have imported an object. I believe that the object is so large that it doesn't fit the environment when zoomed out for a view of its entirity. It would be nice if you could include a python cript to your solution.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: He is referring to a question while I am referring to a problem. We might end up in needing the same solution, but we take different routes. All routes should be available to the beginner, don't you think?

Comment: You do take different routes, which is why I voted to close this question as a duplicate of the previous, older question. The older question already has an answer that uses Python, and uses more accurate terminology. This way, people who search for the problem using either the more technical phrasing, or the way you phrased it will be able to find an answer, since closed questions are linked to their duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know python, however you can change the depth of field to make it bigger or smaller to make you able to see the object in it's entirety.

Go to the Properties Panel (N) -> View -> Clip and change the End distance to increase the field of view and allow the whole object to be seen when zooming out.

Be mindful that it may slow down your computer is the object in question is very big and complex.

Comment: It may be useful to know that you should also increase the near distance also to reduce artefacts like "z-fighting".

I can't see why a big object should slow down rendering. But complexity (mesh, materials) and percentage of the view matters.

Comment: You mean the right thing, but there are a few problems with terminology in this answer: 'Depth of Field' is the range of acceptable_focus_ of a lens (which can also be set on Blender cameras). 'Field of View' generally refers to the limits in X and Y, across and up, not Z, of the view. And the reason bits of the image disappear is the camera has _moved_ closer or further from the target. Strictly speaking, this is not 'zooming', which is changing the focal length of the lens.